# How do I make a trait that I can mix into mapped fields to that I don not have to override the same properties for many fields in a database?

Tags: scala, lift

In the Scala Lift framework, how do I make a trait that I can mix into mapped fields to that I don not have to override the same properties for many fields in a database?

I would like to eliminate some redundancy in the code below. Specifically, I do not want to have to repeatedly add:

```
override def writePermission_? = false
override def readPermission_? = false
override def shouldDisplay_? = false
override def show_? = false
override def dbDisplay_? = false
```

for the several db fields. I am thinking that the way to go about this would be to write a trait that looks something like this:

```
trait PrivateField extends ...??? {
    override def writePermission_? = false
    override def readPermission_? = false
    override def shouldDisplay_? = false
    override def show_? = false
    override def dbDisplay_? = false
}
```

and then mix this into the object overrides as follows:

```
object owner extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User) with PrivateField
object status extends MappedInt(this) with PrivateField
```

etc. Is this a good way to approach the problem? If so, any suggestions on how to write the trait? Below is the code for which I want to reduce the redundancy.

```
class Mytable extends LongKeyedMapper[Mytable] with IdPK {

  def getSingleton = Myclass

  object owner extends MappedLongForeignKey(this, User) {
    override def writePermission_? = false
    override def readPermission_? = false
    override def shouldDisplay_? = false
    override def show_? = false
    override def dbDisplay_? = false
  }
  object description extends MappedString(this, 140)
  object name extends MappedString(this, 140)
  object status extends MappedInt(this) {
    override def writePermission_? = false
    override def readPermission_? = false
    override def shouldDisplay_? = false
    override def show_? = false
    override def dbDisplay_? = false
  }
  object entry_number extends MappedInt(this) {
    override def writePermission_? = false
    override def readPermission_? = false
    override def shouldDisplay_? = false
    override def show_? = false
  }
  object quanitity extends MappedDecimal(this, MathContext.DECIMAL64, 2) {
    override def writePermission_? = false
    override def readPermission_? = false
    override def shouldDisplay_? = false
    override def show_? = false
    override def dbDisplay_? = false
  }
}

object Mytable extends Mytable with LongKeyedMetaMapper[Mytable] with CRUDify[Long, Mytable] {

  override def editMenuLoc:Box[Menu] = Empty
  override def deleteMenuLoc:Box[Menu] = Empty
  override def viewMenuLoc:Box[Menu] = Empty
  override def createMenuLocParams: List[Loc.AnyLocParam] = List(If(User.loggedIn_? _, "Not logged in"))
  override def showAllMenuLocParams: List[Loc.AnyLocParam] = List(If(User.loggedIn_? _, "Not logged in"))

  override def findForList(start: Long, cnt: Int): List[Mytable] =
    findAll(StartAt(start), MaxRows(cnt), By(owner, User.currentUser))

  override def findForParam(in: String): Box[Mytable] =
    for {
      user <- User.currentUser
      id <- Helpers.asLong(in)
      mytable <- find(By(this.id, id), By(owner, user))
    } yield mytable
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use a [self type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821827/scala-self-type-annotation):

```
trait PrivateField[FieldType <: Any, OwnerType <: Mapper[OwnerType]] {
  self: MappedField[FieldType, OwnerType] =>
  override def writePermission_? = false
  override def readPermission_? = false
  override def shouldDisplay_? = false
  override def show_? = false
}
```

Then you can use it in this manner:

```
MappedInt(this) with PrivateField[Int, Mytable]
```

Comment: Sean, thanks for your response. I copied and pasted your answer exactly as you've posted it, but I got the following error: `trait MappedField takes type parameters
[error]   self: MappedField =>` How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to add type params to the trait so they can be picked up by the field :-)

Comment: Sean - this works, thanks! Just one change needed: You need to add a missing closing square bracket after `Mapper[OwnerType]` so that it is `Mapper[OwnerType]]` (I tried to edit this myself, but edits have to be at least 6 characters and this edit would be only one character).